# How to set virtualenvironent in Django so it redirects to proper Location

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am virtuallenvwrapper to isolate my Django Projects, but I can't point it to the required location on **Workon my_project**

How to fix this Issue ?

I reffered this site for installation:http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

I am pretty sure this is a duplicate question ,but I couldn't find it anywhere.Please help **Coders**?

Comment: What happens? What error do you get?

Comment: This is not a error , It enters the virtual Environment .But I want more specifically to come automatically to required location

Comment: I have tried in web for weeks , But could not find suitable solution

Comment: I humbly request you not to downvote such genuine queries, it  may be mostly duplicate.But could not find the apt answer anywhere in net

Comment: So when you type `workon my_project`, you want it to change to the project's directory automagically?

Comment: Yeah Excatly @FlipperPA ,Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to switch to a directory after activating a `virtualenv` with `virtualenvwrapper`, you can tie into the `postactivate` hook:

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#postactivate

That should do the trick, and there's an example in the documentation.

For example, I keep my virtualenvs in my home directory, at `/home/me/.virtualenvs/`. I create a new one with `mkvirtualenv project`, and I now have a directory for it, `/home/me/.virtualenvs/project`. I can then edit `/home/me/.virtualenvs/project/bin/postactivate` and change the directory to where my project is.

Comment: I tried  $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR/postactivate command inside the virtual Enviroment I wanted to hook, but I get a Permission denied and even super user previeleges doesnt allow me to work

Comment: You won't want to use `sudo` or `su` because that'll make you `root` by default, which won't have the `virtualenv` you're trying to use. I've amended my answer with an example, I hope it helps.

Comment: But FlipperPA should I run this command inside virtual environment.Also what is meaning of /home/me(is it virtual Env Location)

Comment: `/home/me/.virtualenvs` is the location where my virtualenvs are saved (in my home directory). That is a default, although it can be changed. The `postactivate` command is what is run after the `workon` command, so you can change to your project directory then. If you're looking to get to your virtualenv directory, once it is active, you can type `cdsitepackages`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using the vitualenvironment which is by default , but instead I use :virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

So at desired location I go there and make a virutal environment like:

```
 $ mkvirtualenv virtual
```

And to map it to my loacation So I can use any time inside the virtualenvironment I wrap to the required loacation like:

```
# Map project path to virtualenv
(virtual)$ setvirtualenvproject $VIRTUAL_ENV $(pwd)
```

I know @FlipperPA explained the concept really well.This is just a broad discription of what I did in my case